# How is the Fermiac machine (Monte Carlo trolley) working?

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-process

There is a [cool website](http://datab.us/i/FERMIAC) showing the Markov chain with a machine.

[image: Fermiac machine]

But nobody is explaining how it's working or showing a video of it's functioning. This is explaining the Markov chain monte carlo in a visual fashion.

Can someone explain the way a machine like on the image can reproduce a Markov chain?

Was it really drawing pictures like this one?

[image: Cool image]

Comment: There's a vague explanation here, near the end: http://hackaday.com/2015/09/11/fermiac-the-computer-that-advanced-the-manhattan-project/

Comment: You've never seen a video?

Comment: NB It's a device for Monte-Carlo. Function is best described by (https://en.sif.it/journals/sif/ncc/econtents/2016/039/02/article/24). Further information with linked references: 1. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FERMIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FERMIAC) 2. [https://en.sif.it/journals/sif/ncc/econtents/2016/039/02/article/24](https://en.sif.it/journals/sif/ncc/econtents/2016/039/02/article/24)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much more detailed description (including available here:

https://docplayer.net/59690734-The-fermiac-or-fermi-s-trolley.html

The abstract from this journal article states:

> [...] A replica of the Fermiac was built at INFN mechanical workshops of
>   Bologna in 2015, on behalf of the Museo Storico della Fisica e Centro Studi
>   e Ricerche “Enrico Fermi”, thanks to the original drawings made available by
>   Los Alamos National Laboratory (LANL). This reproduction of the Fermiac was
>   put in use, and a simulation was developed.